# Make a space-separated list of selected characters in a filename

Tags: python, regex, list

I have a set of files in a directory with names such as:

`"34_R1.fastq", "100_R1.fastq", "100_R2.fastq", "EF23_R1.fastq"`

and I want to make a space-separated list of the characters before the first underscore, without duplicates. My desired output with just the files above would be `"34 100 EF23"`.

I have written a python script to begin this process, but I have noticed that the output is incorrect. There is obviously duplicates because I haven't written code yet to process those, but this is because I can't get the output to correctly separate the numeric/alphanumeric characters before the underscore. Any thoughts on how my code is incorrect?

```
# In directory with all files
import os
import re

file1 = open("RIL_list.txt", "a")

for filename in os.listdir("."):
    m = re.split("_", filename)[0]
    file1.writelines(' '.join(m))

file1.close()
```

The output is incorrect using this code as numbers and alphanumeric characters get separated in the process. I would end up with `file1` containing something like `"34 1 00 10 0E F2 3"` from above.

Comment: have you tried simply doing `filename.split('_')[0]`? then you would just need to put your results in a `set` to remove dupes

Comment: I can't reproduce this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to implement @aws_apprentice's suggestion (that doesn't require using a regex):

```
import os


dir_path = "./test_dir"
matches = set()

for filename in os.listdir(dir_path):
    sep = filename.split("_")
    if len(sep) > 1:
        matches.add(sep[0])  # Add characters preceding first "_".

if matches:
    with open("RIL_list.txt", "w") as file1:
        file1.write(' '.join(matches) + '\n')
```

The contents of the output file would be the following for the sample files you have in your question:

```
EF23 34 100
```

#### Update

You can do things in a more object-oriented and succinct way by using the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) module instead of the `os` module.

```
from pathlib import Path


matches = set()

for filepath in Path("./test_dir").iterdir():
    sep = filepath.stem.split("_")
    if len(sep) > 1:
        matches.add(sep[0])  # Add characters preceding first "_".

if matches:
    Path("RIL_list.txt").write_text(" ".join(matches) + '\n')
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `len(sep) >= 1`, or equivalent?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Works as needed.

Comment: @AMC: No. I'm using `> 1` to weed out any files that don't have at least one `"_"` in their name.

Comment: @martineau You're right, I confused the number of `'_'` with the number of elements in the split list.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use regex for this. It may be overkill, but will be extremely handy if you need to make any changes to which parts of the string you extract.

```py
import re

patt = re.compile(r"(.+)_")

file_names = ["34_R1.fastq", "100_R1.fastq", "100_R2.fastq", "EF23_R1.fastq"]

matches = set()

for f_name in file_names:
    match_res = patt.match(f_name)
    if match_res:
        matches.add(match_res.group(1))

with open('../out/temp_out.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    out_file.write(' '.join(matches))
```

Content of `'temp_out.txt'` after execution:

```
EF23 34 100
```

Comment: Premature optimization is the root… `;¬)`

Comment: @martineau Does that apply to "optimizations" meant to increase flexibility, not performance, though?

Comment: You're right it's not an optimization. Should have referred to the [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) principle (or perhaps [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle))

Comment: @martineau Eh, I'm not sure I agree, since it's such a trivial thing.

Comment: Did you miss the wink? Regardless, since the OP might be a novice, I think leaving the bells and whistles out is probably appropriate (although they obviously know a little bit about regexes…)

Comment: @martineau _Did you miss the wink?_ ;p _since the OP might be a novice, I think leaving the bells and whistles out is probably appropriate_ Good point, I hadn't though about that.